# Same Header Infomation on Different size pages in the same document

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to be able to have the data entered in the first page header be shown on all subsequent pages. This is easy if all the pages are all the same size. How can this be achived if the pages are of varying orintation throughout the document? My users contruct documents using templates which they copy and paste into the document they are creating. Each document contains the same front page template but all subsequent pages can be of different orintations (and maybe different sizes i.e.A4, A3 etc). I want the users to be able to enter the header infomation on the front page which is reflected on all other pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is restrictions to using the same header and footer across pages with different sizes or orientations. Just create your header and footer on the first page and it will repeat on subsequent pages.